# SharePoint PnP Results only from the SharePoint Page (Not all Decoments from our company)

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-designer

Quick question: How can I configure that when my colleagues search on my SharePoint webside that the results are only the Documents, Links e.g. from this page.

Right now when I search with PnP, documents (and more) appear as results of all of our company's published documents.

This is not optimal...

How can i fix that?

Thank you!

***Information: I am using SharePoint on Office Online (newest Version)***